# Selling in-app services from an other app

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I was wandering if I can sell digital objects(like lives in Candy Crush) from an other app. 
I'll explain it a little better: I have an android game built with AppInventor from which I can't implement in-app billing. I was thinking to build an app in java and allowing in-app purchase from it an sharing purchases info on the server on which the game is based.

The question is: does Google allow me to do this or there is some restriction I've not been able to find?

I hope you can understand what I wrote as english is not my mothertongue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't there a way you can just reimplement your game with in app billing? Having to open another app to buy things on this one seems not really intuitive. Plus, you may need to advertise the "buying app" in the "game app" somehow, so you'll still need to write some code.

As far as I remember, AppInventor apps were fairly straightforward to redo if you know how to code Android, plus it's not available anymore, which means you lost support in case you want to do something else.

Comment: Yes, I know AppInventor's issues but the game is not developed by me and the game inventor can't code in java(I'm able to) so he I was thinking to the solution I explained before to solve the situation.

Comment: At the end: do you know if there is any problem with google doing that?

Comment: My bets are you cannot. In app billing involves defining products in the play store application where you buy these products. You could define these products in your app, and make the user sign in with google plus, for instance. That way, you could pair your bought products with an account by saving it in a server, and then synchronize it with the game by logging in and checking what each user bought. I see it fairly impossible for your friend, as logging in and syncing stuff is far away from AppInventor limits. If the game is worth the stuff you want to sell, make the game together

Comment: Well, the game already have a server side with its login which has already been implemented in the game by my friend. At this point my idea was to define products in the google console and then request login on both google and game server to complete the purchase(or maybe the game is already based on google login..I don't know) Thanks for your help

Comment: @AlbertoBrambilla since looks like my answer helped you, would you be so kind to accept it?